# What is the maximal compact subgroup of $SO(2,2)$?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Consider the orthogonal group corresponding to the quadratic form $Q(\vec{x}) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_3^2 - x_4^2 $, then $SO(Q, \mathbb{R}) \simeq SO(2,2)$.  We could think of this as the group of $4 \times 4$ matrices leaving the diagonal matrix invariant under conjugation:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] $$

The main symmetries I can think of are the rotations that change the first two variables, and the second two variables.

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{rc|cc}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta & 0 & 0 \\
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]  ,
\left[ \begin{array}{cc|rc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
0 & 0 & -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array}\right]
 $$

This is a copy of the rotation group $SO(2) \times SO(2) \hookrightarrow SO(2,2) $ and there are two distict  copies.

Comment: Letting $D = diag(1,1,i,i)$ and $Q(Dx)=  \|x\|^2$ you can look at $D^{-1} SU(4,\Bbb{C}) D\cap GL(4,\Bbb{R}) = \{ D^{-1} A D, A\in SU(4,\Bbb{C}), \overline{A} = D^2 A D^2\}$